# How to use androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$RecycleListView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, runtime-error

I am trying to use recycler view but I get an error.

After searching lots of things I found out I have to migrate in Androidx, when my project migrate in Androidx then it will automatically resolve.

[image: stack trace]

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: check whether your using `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` or `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`

Comment: Hey vishal instead of providing image link plese upload your error here.

Answer (score 1):

Use AndroidX version of the RecyclerView instead the support library.
You can't mix the two up, you have to use one or the other. Since android is pushing to move to AndroidX, this should be the choice.

For example convert `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` to this `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

To

```
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

Also put on your dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```